PHP json_decode multiple arrays or array in array to database
I have json from another system, how to store in oracle database? I dont mind if using while or for or what ever, i only hope can store in database in 4 rows without null line as null line provided by another system. I already refer to many question but not find similar case data like mine.
This is then json example
{
  "ErrorCode": "00",
  "ErrorMessage": "",
  "ServiceList": {
    "ServiceDetail": [
      {
        "Service_name": [
          "LTE_DATA_PRI_1",
          "LTE_ONM_PRI_2"
        ],
        "AVLAN": [
          "LTE_DATA_PRI_SITE_1",
          "LTE_DATA_PRI_SITE_2"
        ],
        "IpAddress": [
          "192.168.1/20",
          "192.168.2/20"
        ],
        "AggPort": [
          "GigabitEthernet 1/1/10.1000",
          "GigabitEthernet 1/1/10.1001"
        ]
      },
      "\r\n",
      "\r\n",
      {
        "Service_name": [
          "LTE_DATA_SEC_1",
          "LTE_ONM_SEC_2"
        ],
        "AVLAN": [
          "LTE_DATA_SEC_SITE_1",
          "LTE_DATA_SEC_SITE_2"
        ],
        "IpAddress": [
          "192.168.3/20",
          "192.168.4/20"
        ],
        "AggPort": [
          "GigabitEthernet 1/1/10.1003",
          "GigabitEthernet 1/1/10.1004"
        ]
      },
      "\r\n",
      "\r\n"
    ]
  }
}

expected display or store in database
should be
below is my code in php file but it only save the primary
$i = 0;
$x = 0;

$arrayLength = count($array['ServiceList']['ServiceDetail']);

while ($x < $arrayLength)
{
    
    $arrayLength2 = count($array['ServiceList']['ServiceDetail'][$x]['AVLAN']);
    
    while ($i < $arrayLength2)
    {
        $AVLAN1 = $array['ServiceList']['ServiceDetail'][$x]['AVLAN'];
        
        if ( $AVLAN1 !== null){
    
        $p_avlan = $array['ServiceList']['ServiceDetail'][$x]['AVLAN'][$i];
        $p_agg_port = $array['ServiceList']['ServiceDetail'][$x]['AggPort'][$i];
        $p_ip_address = $array['ServiceList']['ServiceDetail'][$x]['IpAddress'][$i];
        $p_service_name = $array['ServiceList']['ServiceDetail'][$x]['Service_name'][$i];
        
        // sql procedure here //

        $i++;
    
        }
    } // while 2
    $x++;
} // while 1



Using foreach instead of while loops spares you from having to count entries and keeping your own loop index.
On the inner level, loop over the Service_name entry, and then use the key of that loop to access the corresponding elements in the other arrays on the same level.
foreach($array['ServiceList']['ServiceDetail'] as $serviceDetail) {
    if(is_array($serviceDetail)) {
        foreach($serviceDetail['Service_name'] as $key => $p_service_name) {
            $p_avlan = $serviceDetail['AVLAN'][$key];
            $p_ip_address = $serviceDetail['IpAddress'][$key];
            $p_agg_port = $serviceDetail['AggPort'][$key];
        
            var_dump($p_service_name, $p_avlan, $p_ip_address, $p_agg_port);
        }
    }
}

https://3v4l.org/O9MWM
